# динамически обновлять количество подписчиков Laravel, Ajax, VueJS

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js, laravel5

столкнулась с проблемой. Не получатся динамически обновлять количество подписчиков (без перезагрузки страницы). Я только учусь, если есть другой вариант проще, можете подсказать пожалуйста

Так же есть кнопка, надпись которой меняется в зависимости от статуса (подписан/отписан)

```html
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-3 text-center numb">{{$followCount}}</div>
      <div class="col-3 text-center numb">{{$followingCount}}</div>
    </div>

    <example-component follow-count="{{$followCount}}" user-id='{{ $user->id }}' follow='{{ $follow }}'></example-component>
```

количество подписчиков и подписок подсчитывается в контроллере

```php
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
  public function index(User $user)
  {
      $followCount=$user->profile->followers->count();
      $followingCount=$user->following->count();
      return view('profiles.index', compact('user', 'follow', 'postCount', 'followCount', 'followingCount'));
  }
}
```

vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
          <div class="col-12 text-center"><button class="btn btn-primary" @click="follows" v-text="buttonText"></button></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['userId', 'follow'],
        data: function () {
            return {
                status: this.follow,


            }
        },
        methods: {
            follows() {
                axios.post('/follow/' + this.userId)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.status =! this.status;
                    });
            }
        },
        computed: {
            buttonText() {
                return (this.status) ? 'Folgen' : 'Abonniert';
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

так, у меня получаются следующие файлы в resources/js/components
ExampleComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
          <div class="col-12 text-center"><button class="btn btn-primary" @click="follows" v-text="buttonText"></button></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import FollowBus from 'FollowBus'
    export default {
        props: ['userId', 'follow', 'followCount'],
        data: function () {
            return {
                status: this.follow,

            }
        },
        mounded: function() {
         // отслеживаем status
         this.$watch('status', (newStatus, oldStatus) => {
            FollowBus.$emit('follow_change', newStatus)
         })
        },
        methods: {
            follows() {
                axios.post('/follow/' + this.userId)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.status =! this.status;
                        console.log(this.followCount);
                    });


            }
        },
        computed: {
            buttonText() {
                return (this.status) ? 'Abonniert' : 'Folgen';
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

FollowCounter.vue

```
<template>
 <div class="col-3 text-center numb">{{followCount}}</div>
</template>
<script>
   import FollowBus from 'FollowBus'

   export default {
      data: function () {
         return {
            count: 0
         }
      },
      mounted: function () {
        // подписываемся на событие
        FollowBus.$on('follow_change', (status) => {
           // подгрузка при возникновении события
           this.loadCounters()
        })

        // подгрузка при монтировании
        this.loadCounters()
      },
      methods: {
         loadCounters: function () {
            axios.get(url).then((response) => {
              // извлекаем данные из response.data
              // this.count =
            })
         }
      }
  }
</script>
```

FollowBus.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'

export default FollowBus = new Vue();
```

при этом видарт ошибку Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'FollowBus'

Comment: Если ответ ниже помог вам — отметте его, как решение.

Answer (score 0):

создать компонент - шину событий (файл FollowBus.js)

```
import Vie from 'vue'

export default FollowBus = new Vie();
```

при изменении статуса в вашем компоненте (example-component) послать событие в шину

```
...
<script>
   import FollowBus from 'FollowBus'

   export default {
      ...
      mounded: function() {
         // отслеживаем status 
         this.$watch('status', (newStatus, oldStatus) => {
            FollowBus.$emit('follow_change', newStatus)
         })
      }
      ...
   }
</script>
```

в компоненте вывода количества подписчиков (назовем FollewerCounter.vue) подписаться на событие, подгружать подписчиков по событию 'follow_change'

код FollewerCounter.vue

```js
    <template>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-3 text-center numb">{{followCount}}</div>
          <div class="col-3 text-center numb">{{followingCount}}</div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
       import FollowBus from 'FollowBus'

       export default {
          data: function () {
             return {
                followCount: 0,
                followingCount: 0,
             }
          },
          mounted: function () {
            // подписываемся на событие
            FollowBus.$on('follow_change', (status) => {
               // подгрузка при возникновении события
               this.loadCounters()
            })

            // подгрузка при монтировании
            this.loadCounters()
          },
          methods: {
             loadCounters: function () {
                axios.get(url).then((response) => {
                  // извлекаем данные из response.data
                  // this.count = 
                })
             }
          }
      }
    </script>
```

подключаем компонент в файле инициализации приложения app.js (или main.js) аналогично example-component

```js
Vue.component('folower-couner', '<путь>/FollewerCounter.vue')
```

добавляем в html

```html
<folower-couner></folower-couner>
<exanle-component ...></exanle-component>
```

в контроллере laravel

```
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function index(User $user)
    { 
       ... 
       получение данных
       ... 

       if ($request->ajax()) {
          // для ajax запросов
          $data = compact('followCount', 'followingCount'));

          return response()
            ->json($data, 200)
            ->setEncodingOptions(JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
       }

       $data = compact('user', 'follow', 'postCount'));        
       return return view('profiles.index', $data);
    }
 }
```

Comment: большое спасибо! не подскажите, как интегрировать код в готовый компонент, т.е. в ExampleComponent.vue?

Comment: я не совсем до конца понимаю принцип, но не получается интегрировать. Где в HTML нужно вставить follow-component? Выше приложила измененный код

Comment: follow-component вместо верстки вывода счетчиков, верстку перенести в шаблон компонента FollewerCounter.vue

Comment: постоянно видеть ошибку  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'FollowBus'

Comment: попробуйте в начале пути указать ./ (текущая директория):
import FollowBus from './FollowBus.js'